# AC current amplifier with pwm current control

Tags: mosfet, current-source, constant-current, mosfet-driver, current-signal

I'm starting to build a piece of test equipment to test a trip device for switch gear breakers.  I need to amplify an AC current source.  When the breaker is in service the trip device receives its current sensing from the secondary of the ct on the breaker.

I want to be able to control the current via PWM as I plan on using a TI microcontroller for the brain of the system.  I'm struggling with the AC amplification section.  I am trying to find the LED drivers that have a external MOSFET and try it as I would have current sensing and could PWM control it.  Then I could use the MOSFET I need as I need to be as close to 60 amps as I can be.

What do y'all think?

Thanks!
Jake

Comment: I think it's very difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve. Do you have a schematic? When you say "amplify the current", where does the extra power come from?

Comment: Thanks Nick,  I think current amplifier may have been a poor choice of words. It looks like my dropbox didnt sync so I cant get to my preliminary schematic at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Nick,  I think current amplifier may have been a poor choice of words. It looks like my dropbox didnt sync so I cant get to my preliminary schematic at the moment.   This system will be powered from 120vac but can be rectified to DC, so I have that available as a power source.  An adjustable AC constant current source would be a better term I think for this.  I was thinking amplification as a method to adjust the current level. My other thought was an inverter circuit.  It has been to long since I have had an electronics class.  Thanks again, Ill get the flow chart and schematic up soon

Comment: So, you want to generate a current-regulated AC waveform, and you have AC mains power to work with, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and yes.     Looking a bit further into this I can use the TI MSP432 and use one of the current outputs (20mA max) to drive a op amp which can drive the high I MOSFET.   Thanks again for putting up with me!

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do this with a MOSFET, because MOSFETs have body diodes, so you can't use them for switching AC. I'll leave it to someone with more knowledge of AC power to provide a better solution.

Comment: Are you looking to build something like this?  http://us.megger.com/circuit-breaker-test-set-cb-1/